# Type backslash more easily on Japanese wireless keyboard

Tags: keyboard, xcode

In order to write \ on a Japanese wireless keyboard we have to use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>¥</kbd>. Very very inconvenient actually. Especially with Swift, the use of \ will sky rocket... Alt is bottom left, right of <kbd>caps</kbd>, and <kbd>¥</kbd> is left of <kbd>delete</kbd>. You absolutely need two hands for this, and alt is close to caps and ¥ is close to delete so all kind of havoc will break loose from time to time.

[image]

Is there anyway to remap this key? Of course I'm mostly using Xcode. Ideally I'd like to remap \ to  <kbd>_</kbd>  which is left of the right <kbd>shift</kbd>. Because  <kbd>_</kbd>  prints _ both for shifted and unshifted taps, so \ for an unshifted tap would be great.

Comment: I was able to download and use Ukulele from http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele however while the software seems powerful it's far from easy to use and have keyboards install. The manual is lengthy and takes a while to go through. There's no quick way of fixing things, unless you have a lot of experience I guess. The keyboard layout I created seems to work in Notes, but it does not work in Google Chrome (I couldn't write this comment using it)

Comment: Ok so I restarted Google Chrome and can now use the keyboard layout. Seems to work, look \\\\ :-)

Comment: Care to make that a answer so we can close this topics

Comment: This might be related? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158975/how-do-i-get-a-backslash-when-in-japanese-input-mode-in-yosemite/158976#158976

Answer (score 1):

I was able to download and use Ukulele from http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele  however while the software seems powerful it's far from easy to use and have keyboards install. The manual is lengthy and takes a while to go through. There's no quick way of fixing things, unless you have a lot of experience I guess. The keyboard layout I created seems to work in Notes, but it does not work in Google Chrome (I couldn't write this comment using it)

Ok so I restarted Google Chrome and can now use the keyboard layout. Seems to work, look \\ :-)

And to add something... Ukulele works on an inherent feature of OS X (the keyboard layout files), just adds an UI on top of it. It would be nice with a simpler solution so if anyone knows feel free to add an answer.

Comment: great, now you just check it as done (as soon as it is available)