# How do I get a backslash when in Japanese input mode in MacOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, japanese

I've run in Japanese input mode for 6 years now. I generally had no issues. Now with OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) I can no longer type a backslash. This means in order to use the Terminal I have to completely get out of Japanese input and switch it US input where as before Yosemite if I was in Romanji mode things just worked.

How can I either (a) get it to work like it did before or (b) how do I type a backslash while in Japanese Input mode?

Note: Backslash is used in the Terminal and when programming very often. I can't imagine there isn't some way to fix this otherwise Japanese programmers would be up in arms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out there's a setting in Keyboard Settings. Change `"¥" key generates` to `\ (Backslash)`

No idea why Yosemite changed that setting from whatever it used to be or if it didn't exist before why they felt the need to change the behavior.

[image: keyboard control panel]

Google's Japanese IME has a similar option

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer [here](http://www.marshalltradecorp.com/coDe/misc/macbook-pro-type-underscore-backslash-japanese-keyboard.html) and again [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1632122?answerId=7720207022#7720207022)

> If you hold down the "alt option" key on your MacBook keyboard and then hit the  ¥ key, it will type a backslash.